# Security access not working in spring boot

Tags: security, spring-boot

I have a login page in spring boot and now I want that page to show only specific links.
Furthermore, my ADMIN User is created during startup, being done with my import.sql

```
INSERT INTO benutzer(id, created_at, anzeigename, benutzername, dienstnummer, passwort) VALUES (nextval('benutzer_idbenutzer_seq'), now(), 'ADMIN', 'ADMIN', '', 'xxx');

INSERT INTO rolle(id, created_at, bezeichnung) VALUES (nextval('benutzer_idbenutzer_seq'), now(), 'ADMIN');
```

This is a part of my SecurityConfig class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/registration**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
}
```

And this is my html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
Should only be shown to ADMIN Users
</div>
```

Maybe someone knows what I am missing?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem now.
One problem was that my ADMIN user was registered with its username ( username was created in my user table ) but not with its user_role.
After having solved this problem, I had to put the following thing in my html file in order to show specific things:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
```

Answer (score 0):

everything that you wrote sames to be fine, check if there is some missed annotation or if the admin was created at the right way.
here is a small example that works fine on my machine:

```
 @Configuration
 public class SecurityConfigurationCompany extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.authorizeRequests()
 .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
 .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
 .antMatchers("/profiles").permitAll()
 .antMatchers("/dislike").hasAuthority("USER")
 .antMatchers("/addParticipant/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
 .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
 .and()
 .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
 .and()
 .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
 }
 }
```

hopefully that was helpful you tell me if it doesnt work

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it with your code, adapting some things. As you said I should check whether my ADMIN account was created the right way, I remembered that when I created a normal user via my registration site and then logged on with this user, the user was recognized as a normal user so I think it has something to do with how I create my ADMIN account when startup. Is there  any other possibility to create the ADMIN user at startup ( but something automatically )?